# Allow user to modify a selected element of a task list

Tags: php, html

I have an html form (and accompanying php code) that allows user to input task names, which are stored in a PHP array $task_list[].

I also have, below the task list, a dropdown from which users can select a desired value. I want to create a button modify which will allow users to change the value they have selected.

For instance, if the task list is:

1. Get up
2. Take a bath
3. Go for a jog
4. Go to school
5. Come back home

A user should be able to select "Go to school", and having done so, click Modify and change that to "Go to work", or something else.

I've made the select dropdown list work and can access the selected value and store it in a variable $selected. But I am completely flummoxed as to how I can allow users to change the value in the $task_list array.

My code–

task_list.php:

```
<form action="." method="post" >
    <!//select dropdown>
    <select name='taskid'>
        <?php foreach( $task_list as $id => $task ) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                <?php echo $task; ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>

    <?php foreach( $task_list as $task ) : ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="tasklist[]" value="<?php echo $task; ?>">
    <?php endforeach; ?>    

    <br />

    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value='modify'>
    <input type=submit value="Modify Task">

    <br />

    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value='promote'>
    <input type=submit value="Promote Task">
</form>
```

index.php:

```
//get selected value
function getSelected()
{
    if(isset($_POST['taskid']))
    {
        $myvalue = $_POST['taskid'];
    }

    else
    {
        $myvalue = $task_list[0];
    }

    return $myvalue;
}

//skipping ahead to modify field (all other buttons work perfectly):
case 'modify':
    $myval = getSelected();   //$myval returns index of selected item
    $selected = $task_list[$myval];   //selected item

    break;
```

I just want to allow the user to click modify and change the value they selected in the $task_list array.

Thank you.

Comment: And how did you define `$task_list`?

Comment: You don't need the hidden `action` inputs, and they won't work as you've done it. Use `name="action"`  on the submit buttons, then `$_POST['action']` will tell you which button was clicked.

Comment: Add a text input where the user can enter the new value for the task. Then you can assign that value to `$tasklist[$_POST['taskid']]`

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I have many buttons (add task, delete task, sort alphabetically, etc). I've used a hidden action and all these other buttons work as intended. I'm not sure how I can create a user input right there. Should I have an if condition to check if any value has been selected or not and in the if condition, close the `?>` php tag, create an input and then open another `<?php` tag? Is there a better way? Thanks